# Отправить при помощи python случайные 10 символов

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Всем привет! Задача в том чтоб отправить при помощи python случайные 10 символов (включая цифры). Не понимаю, как использовать модуль random

Подскажите, пожалуйста, если можно поподробнее.

```
def send_email(message):
    sender = "....."
    password = "....."
    text = [random.choice('qwert12345') for _ in range(20)]
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()

    try:
        server.login(sender, password)
        server.sendmail(sender, sender, message)

        return "The message was sent successfully"
    except Exception as _ex:
        return f"{_ex}\nCheck your login or password please!"
```

Comment: Начните с малого, для начала удалите весь код с SMTP и попробуйте отдельно сгенерировать хотя бы один случайный символ. Затем, подробнее изучите все возможные функции модуля `random` и подумайте, какая из них больше подходит для вашей задачи.

Comment: Уже готово, отдельно я этот модуль запустил и сгенерировал все 10 символов, просто не доходит как далее его свести с SMTP. Нужно чтоб в заголовке было 10 символов и в самом теле письма так же 10

Comment: вам осталось только преобразовать список в строку и отправить эту строку аргументом в SMTP, преобразовать список можно следующим образом: ''.join(text)

Comment: Спасибо!! Постараюсь!